# Create Apache service with custom httpd.conf file in windows

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, httpd.conf

I have my `custom-httpd.conf` file `c:\apache\conf` Am wondering how do I use this `custom-httpd.conf` file instead of `httpd.conf` file to create Apache service in windows.

Tried the below command but didnt work

```
httpd.exe -k start -k config ..\conf\custom-httpd.conf -n "Apachefacade"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to simply change the default config to point to your custom config:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#include

If you're trying to start a second instance you need a `-f` to specify the config, in your example you've used `-k`

Comment: My goal is to create 2 Apache services one uses `httpd.conf` and another uses `custom-httpd.conf` file

Comment: Isn't that `-f "c:\conf\custom-httpd.conf"`

Answer (score -1):

If you pass a command like this to create your 2nd service:

```
httpd.exe -f conf/2.conf -k install -n server2
```

Then anytime you start the service named "server2" it will start with the alternate configuration specified by -f.

Comment: This is unclear.